# Update Panel asp.net

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I am using an UpdatePaenl in an asp.net page. It has a button to trigger it.
I'm able to show "Loading" when the button is pressed.
Here my issue, I need it to show "Loading" when the page is first called, not just when a button is pressed.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I have the same requirement and have not yet found a solution. As far as I know you cannot trigger the loading image, other than by forcing a postback

Comment: What needs to show the "loading", the text of the button or the content of the updatepanel before it is loaded? Are you using an UpdateProgress control?

Comment: Maybe wrap the whole page in the update panel and set the childern as trigger to true and update mode to alway then have it fire in the page load event for a set of time?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some example code that I created for a photogallery widget:

```
<div>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate> 
            <img src="images/busybar.gif" alt="Loading..." style="margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; position:fixed; top:60%; left:50%;" />
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <uc1:PhotoAlbumThumbnails ID="PhotoAlbumThumbnails1" runat="server" ItemsPerPage="30" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked UpdateProgress control?
http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/overview/UpdateProgressOverview.aspx